# Commerce discount promotions as a fieldtype?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins, fieldtypes, relatedto, promotions

I'd like to create an entry in Craft that talks about a new discount, and then choose that discount via a field (so a bit like you can choose an entry or a product). That way, should the parameters of the discount change, I'm not having to manually update the information in the entry to match any changes to the discount details. Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: ^ I guess the same could apply to commerce subscriptions as well. By the way I'm using Craft 3 and Commerce 2.

Answer (score 3):

That field type doesn’t currently exist, but it wouldn’t be hard to [create it](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/field-types.html#registering-custom-field-types).

Here’s the relevant code you’d need if you want to take a stab at it:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\base\ElementInterface;
use craft\commerce\models\Discount;
use craft\commerce\Plugin as Commerce;

// ...

public function normalizeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{
    if ($value !== null) {
        return Commerce::getInstance()->discounts->getDiscountById($value);
    }

    return $value;
}

public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
{
    $options = [];
    foreach (Commerce::getInstance()->discounts->getAllDiscounts() as $discount) {
        $options[] = ['value' => $discount->id, 'label' => $discount->name];
    }

    /** @var Discount|null $value */
    return Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('_includes/forms/select', [
        'id' => $this->handle,
        'name' => $this->handle,
        'options' => $options,
        'value' => $value->id ?? null,
    ]);
}
```

With that, the field type’s value would always either be a [Discount model](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v2/craft-commerce-models-discount.html) or `null`, so in your templates you could do this:

```twig
{% if entry.myDiscountField %}
    Code: <code>{{ entry.myDiscountField.code }}</code>
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively, you could pull this off with a simple Plain Text field that stores a discount code, and then fetch the discount manually from your template.

```twig
{% if entry.myDiscountCodeField %}
    {% set discount = craft.commerce.discounts.getDiscountByCode(entry.myDiscountCodeField) %}
{% else %}
    {% set discount = null %}
{% endif %}

{% if discount %}
    Code: <code>{{ discount.code }}</code>
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am having a problem after create the discount field. When I try to save the entry with discount field, I got the error "Discount Field should contain at most 255 characters." I checked the code in the field, and commented out "normalizeValue" function. Or instead of commenting ```public function normalizeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{
    if ($value !== null) {
        return Commerce::getInstance()->discounts->getDiscountById($value)->id;
    }

    return $value;
}``` might be right?